I can't scale down my bendy bones anymore with CTRL+ALT+S
I'm using blender 4.1 I think this function has changed.  When I switch to bendy bones, I am told I can scale the bones down with CTRL+ALT+S to a reasonable size.  Right now when I press that, it just saves a new version of the file.
Right now it looks like this and I tried doing in POSE and Edit mode.  Did they change shortcut?


It's now AltCtrlShiftS..............


Thank you for this.
